# Free Credit Report -- Checking for identity theft

Tags: credit-report, identity-theft

I'm about to request my free annual credit report. I've never requested one before, but I noticed something suspicious with my FICO score lately in my Discover Card app and want to look into my credit for possible identity theft.

I can get a free report from the three companies, TransUnion, Equifax, and Experian.

It gives the following textual advice about requesting your credit report.

> If you are thinking about buying something big soon - a new car or even a home - you may want to get all of your credit reports now. **That way you can correct any mistakes on all of them right away**.
>
> If you are not planning a big purchase, requesting them over time might be a better choice. **When you spread them out, watch for expected changes or suspicious activity throughout the year**

What I'm confused about is what will appear on each report. Does each company show slightly different information, or do they all show the same thing? If identity theft has happened, will that appear on each credit report, or is it possible that it could only show up on one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does each company show slightly different information, or do they all
>   show the same thing?

They are usually slightly different. It all depends on which agencies your banks use and/or report to. Most things will appear on all 3 reports.

> If identity theft has happened, will that appear on each credit
>   report, or is it possible that it could only show up on one of them?

It is certainly possible for it to only show up on one report. Again, it all depends on which agencies the bank in question reports to.

I would recommend finding out which credit bureau your App is pulling from, and starting with that one. If the anomaly is explained by something you are aware of, you may not need to pull all 3 right now. But if fraud is detected you may wish to pull them all.

Comment: Thanks TTT! I don’t have any big purchases coming up, like a vehicle, and I already own a home. I’ll probably order all three to make sure all is good.